# Python scikit-DBSCAN : wrong coordinate or clustering

Tags: python, dbscan

I am writing DBSCAN , and i meet some strange problem .(2 problem)

Here is my code:

The first part there is a problem, if i add`X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)`  the coordinate of result is wrong! But if i didn't add this code , it always will be one clustering (But the coordinate of result is Right!). i try to adjustment the esp or min_samples, but it didn't change.

```
dataSet = []
fileIn = open('data')
for line in fileIn.readlines():
    lineArr = line.strip().split('\t')
    dataSet.append([float(lineArr[0]), float(lineArr[1])]) 
numSamples = len(dataSet)
X = np.array(dataSet) 
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

[image](add)
[image](without)

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=10).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_
print(labels)

counters = {}
for item in labels:
if item in counters:
    counters[item] += 1
else:
    counters[item] = 1
print ("Count of different cluster:(#r,g,b,a)")#r,g,b,a
print (counters)   
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
```

The Second problem is i try to plot the coordinate that i Compute,but i don't know why it show the result is so wrong!

```
clusters = [np.mean(X[labels == i],axis=0) for i in range(n_clusters_)]

outliers = X[labels == 0]
print(clusters)

for i in range(n_clusters_):
    plt.plot(clusters[i],'*',markersize=20)

unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
          for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o',             markerfacecolor=tuple(col),markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)
    xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)
plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

Please help me thank u!

Comment: What coordinate system are your points?

Comment: Did you figure it out Luo Zin-Han?

Answer (score 2):

You obviously need to **choose epsilon** appropriately for your coordinate system. If you scale the data, the epsilon will no longer be the same. A hack that you max find simpler (but that is not the 'proper' solution) is to simply compute the mean using the *unscaled* data. But the means of DBSCAN clusters are not reliable anyway.

Judging by your axes, you probably need to decrease epsilon by a factor of 100.

As your data apparently is coordinates, you should **use Haversine distance** because Earth is not flat, and choose epsilon based on a distance that makes sense for your problem. The exact scaling may be a bit tricky. It's probably radians, so you need to convert miles to radians to translate distances.

Comment: reprojecting to a local cartesian coordinate system would be an option too (the OP would still need an epsilon)

Comment: Instead of reprojecting (DBSCAN does not do any coordinate calculations itself) he could indeed just compute the mean using the original data. But that won't solve distortion issues introduced by the standard scaler.